# how to make sure images load sequentially

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, onload

Here i have a simple test code which loads a test of images in browser.Here i used asynchronous onload event to add image to dom after it finishes loading. Images load just fine.**Problem is if i continuously reload the page multiple time image sequence change**.As if image-2 loaded before image-1 ,sometimes image-3 loads first, etc.How i can make sure images load sequentially, like first load image1,then image2,image3 etc every time i load the page.How i can do that?

```
var images = ['cat1.png','cat2.jpg','cat3.jpg'];

var i = 0;
images.forEach(function(elem,index,arr){
   var image=new Image();
   image.onload = function(){
       document.body.appendChild(image);
       console.log(++i);
   };
   image.onerror = function(){
       console.log('error occured');

   } 
   image.src = elem;
   image.style.width = '300px';
   image.style.height = '300px';
});
```

[image]

Comment: Use promises https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: But foreach is a synchronous method.It should block everything  until first image loads, isn't it?

Comment: @AL-zami `onload` is an asynchronous event, so the callback of `forEach` does not wait for the image to download, it only starts the download and then continues

Comment: You can't control the order in which the images will finish loading. I think you have two options. Option 1 - set a flag when each image is loaded, you can either display the images when all are loaded, or display the next image in the sequence as soon as it's available. Option 2 - wait until the first one is loaded before you make the request for the second, and so on (but that would of course be slow).

Comment: will using promises solve this types of issue? li @Roberrrt said ?

Comment: @AL-zami http://caniuse.com/#search=promise

Comment: Possibly but you still need to decide what to do - are you going to wait until *all* images have loaded before displaying them, or are you going to do a check after each image is loaded and see if it can be displayed yet?

Comment: which one will be better from performance point of view ?

Comment: From the user's point of view it's best if you can check after each image is loaded - but it is a little more work

Answer (score 4):

You should wait for the *callback* from the `onload` event.
If it's *fired* you can *iterate* and load the next image.
This makes sure the images will be loaded in the right order (as in *array*).

```
var images = [
    'http://d39kbiy71leyho.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/09170020/cats-politics-TN.jpg',
    'error',
    'https://s2.graphiq.com/sites/default/files/stories/t2/tiny_cat_12573_8950.jpg',
    'http://www.bharatint.com/img/categories/our-cat-shop-image.png'
], i = 0;

function loadImageArrayAsync(){
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function(){
        document.body.appendChild(image);
        if (i++ < images.length - 1) loadImageArrayAsync();
    };
    image.onerror = function(){
        if (i++ < images.length - 1) loadImageArrayAsync();
     }
    image.src = images[i];
    image.style.height = '300px';
    image.style.width = '300px';
}

loadImageArrayAsync();
```

Comment: But what happen if one image fail to load..that means other images cant load too

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. It fires off all the image requests in a loop, then when a response is received it does a bit of processing to work out which images can be displayed. This way you don't have to wait for one image to finish loading before requesting the next. The code could probably do with tidying up but you get the idea...

```
    var urls = ["/Content/images/Chrysanthemum.jpg", "/Content/images/Desert.jpg", "/Content/images/Hydwewrangeas.jpg", "/Content/images/Jellyfish.jpg", "/Content/images/Koala.jpg"]
    var numImages = urls.length;
    var images = [numImages];
    var gotResponse = [numImages];
    var maxDisplayed = -1;

    function checkImages(index) {
        // Check if previous images have been displayed
        if (maxDisplayed == index - 1) {
            for (i = index; i <= numImages; i++) {
                // Check if we've received a response for this image
                if (gotResponse[i] !== true) {
                    break;
                }
                maxDisplayed = i;
                if (images[i] != null) {
                    console.log('Adding image ' + i);
                    document.body.appendChild(images[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function imageError(index) {
        console.log('Error loading image ' + index);
        images[index] = null;
        gotResponse[index] = true;
        checkImages(index);
    }

    function imageLoaded(index, image) {
        console.log('Loaded image ' + index);
        images[index] = image;
        gotResponse[index] = true;
        checkImages(index);
    }

    function loadImages() {
        $.each(urls, function(index, value) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.onload = function () {
                imageLoaded(index, image);
            }
            image.onerror = function () {
                imageError(index);
            }
            image.src = value;
            image.style.width = '300px';
            image.style.height = '300px';
        });
    }

    loadImages();
```

Sample output:

```
Error loading image 2
Loaded image 3
Loaded image 0
Adding image 0
Loaded image 1
Adding image 1
Adding image 3
Loaded image 4
Adding image 4
```