# I would like to load images in a "wave"..

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<html>
<section>

<style>
img{
 width: 150px;
 height:150px;
 float:left;
 }
 </style>
 </section>


 <script>

 var img = undefined,
 section = document.querySelector('section'),
 images=[
 "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-0.jpg",
 "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-1.jpg",
 "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-2.jpg",
 "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-3.jpg",
 "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-4.jpg",
 "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-5.jpg",
 "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-6.jpg"
  ];

  function loadImage( i ){
   img = document.createElement('img');
   section.appendChild(img);
   img.dataset['index'] = i;
   img.src=images[i];
 }
 for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){

  loadImage(i)

  }

  </script>


  </html>
```

This is my code, at the moment I receive all the images at the same time...
I would like to load each image only when the previous one has been load..

Any help will be gratitude

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make sure images load sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506073/how-to-make-sure-images-load-sequentially)

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign a pseudorecursive callback to the onload handler:

```
function loadImage( i ){
  if(i >= images.length) return;
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  section.appendChild(img);
  img.dataset['index'] = i;
  img.src=images[i];
  img.onload = () => loadImage(i+1);
}

loadImage(0);
```

Or use some new ES 7 stuff:

```
(async function(){

 for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  section.appendChild(img);
  img.dataset['index'] = i;
  img.src=images[i];

  await new Promise(r => image.onload = r );
 }

 })()
```

Comment: `onloaf` - yummmm

Comment: @ochi yeah sorry, was interrupted while writing :/

Comment: no worries... it's no biggie... just poking fun at the typo... :)

Comment: A [loaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaf) (typically of bread) would be a yummy thing to wait for (it would be nice and warm).  So an `onloaf` event, well.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably some `setTimeout` along with recursion can give a nice effect:

```js
var img = undefined,
  section = document.querySelector('section'),
  images = [
    "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-0.jpg",
    "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-1.jpg",
    "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-2.jpg",
    "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-3.jpg",
    "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-4.jpg",
    "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-5.jpg",
    "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-number-6.jpg"
  ];

function loadImage(i) {
  img = document.createElement('img');
  section.appendChild(img);
  img.dataset['index'] = i;
  img.src = images[i];
}

var index = 0;
function loadNext() {
  if(index < images.length) {
    loadImage(index);
    
    setTimeout(function(idx){  
      loadNext();
    },200, index++);
  }
}

loadNext();
```

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<section>


</section>


</html>
```